# why the currentThread method does NOT have the method BODY?

Tags: java

In the class Thread in java.lang package we have

```
public class Thread implements Runnable{
    ...
    public static native Thread currentThread();
    ....
}
```

the class Thread is not an abstract class, so why the *currentThread* method does NOT have **BODY**??

Answer (score 0):

The `native` keyword states that this method implementation is internal and not in Java but in platform-dependent code.